# Display an base64 image retrieved from a REST webservice in webform

Tags: asp.net, rest, qt, opencv, tobase64string

I am newbi in asp.net and Restful websevice.
I want to send my picture from my Qt project to my Server with the Rest api.
I read my image with opencv and convert it to the base64 and send it through the url like this :

```
Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\piltan\\Downloads\\remove.jpg");
cv::resize(img,img,Size(30,30));
string encoded = base64_encode(img.data, img.rows *img.cols);
QString qenc = QString::fromStdString(encoded);
//cout<<encoded<<endl;
//qenc = "sa";
QEventLoop eventLoop;
QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
QObject::connect(&mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*))
,&eventLoop,SLOT(quit()));
QNetworkRequest req( QUrl( QString("http://localhost:60733/api/Weather? 
id=")+qenc) );
```

in Server side i have a controller class that in which receive my image string successfully.

This is my receive method :

[image]

And retrieve string length to my Qt client.

This is my output :

```
  "Image length 1200"
```

So i can successfully send and recieve my data.
Now I want to show this base64 image in a webform and browser.
I added a new webform to my project and placed a webcontrol image in that:

[image]
But i dont know how to assign received data to my placed image object.
As i saied i am newbi and am not familiar with Rest api.
Can anybody help me ? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to upload image separately to your webserver instead of sending it as base64. Specially if you use URL or JSON request to send base64 data, there are some limits in the size of your request body and can be problematic for you app and server backend.

Instead you can use HTTP `multipart` request and send your image data using that.

Here is a link to a Gist where you can see a working example of that:
https://gist.github.com/wzyuliyang/ffc0217015658b87e3fd

It is using *python* as server backend, but the whole process is what you want. For example in Qt implementation you can see how to send your image data using `moltipart` form data:

```
//path image
QString path("d:\\people3.jpeg");
//php script that receives the image
QNetworkRequest requete(QUrl("http://*.*.*.*:8080/upload"));

QByteArray boundary = "------WebKitFormBoundarytoHka8LUGjq34sBN";
QFile file(path);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    qDebug()<<"error read image";
    return;
}
QByteArray fileContent(file.readAll());

QByteArray data = boundary + "\r\n";
data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"people3.jpeg\"\r\n";
data += "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + fileContent + "\r\n";
data += boundary + "--\r\n";
requete.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarytoHka8LUGjq34sBN");
requete.setRawHeader("Content-Length", QString::number(data.size()).toLatin1 ());
file.close();
QNetworkAccessManager *am = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkReply *reply = am->post(requete,data);

QObject::connect(am, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Hope it helps.

**Update:**

Using this approach you will have an image file stored in your server and then you can set the `src` attribute of `img` tag to view it. For example:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/images/myimg.jpg">
```

But if you want to display base64 content on image you should do like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk...">
```

So in your ASP.NET web form, assuming you have an image control named `image1`, you can show base64 image like this:

```
string imgString = "/9j/4AAQSk..."; // Place your actual base64 string here
image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imgString);
```

Furthermore if you included the image type in string, you can simply use this:

```
string imgString = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk..."; // Place your actual base64 string here
image1.ImageUrl = imgString;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Amoo Hesam.But my problem is on the server side.i can send small images at this time.I want to show my received image on a webform. do you have a solution for that??

Comment: @naserpiltan You're welcome! , What I wanna say is that you can save images in your backend and then show them as a normal image, instead of a base64 image. But I've added related code to show base64 images also. Please see my updated answer.